# Advantages of different layouts vs different values files in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I am relatively new to android app programming. I am creating an app that needs to support multiple screens and my question is:

What are the advantages of having a completely different layout file for each different screen sizes i.e. `layout` `layout-small` `layout-large` ect. versus having one layout with different `values` files containing different dimension files?

Comment: Isn't it easier to add some dimen-values than creating separate layouts for each type of screen size?

Comment: That is what I want to know. Which is more efficient and what is easier?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The advantage of having a different layout file is the possibility of using a totally different layout structure on different devices.

Imagine an app consisting of two fragments. In smalls devices only one fragment at a time could be shown, while in larger devices you could setup your layout to show both of them at once.

Comment: Okay that makes sense. And for further clarification if my app had a few different activities (pages so to speak) can I have individual layouts for different screen sizes or does it have to be all of them for each size?

Comment: It should be a matter of convenience. If your layout structure is gonna change on different screen sizes, use several layout files. If you can achieve the result you want just by using qualified values files, go for that solution as it is much more simple.

Answer (score 1):

**Using Different Layout:** If you use different layout for each screen you have to re-create same multiple layouts(that means multiple containers, textviews, buttons etc) which will cause redundancy. That would be pretty annoying and  increase your app size unnecessarily.

**Using Different Screen-sizes :** If you use `values` for different dpi of devices, you only have to define different values for each type of dpi using just one layout file. Which makes more sense and much easier. Hope this clears things up a bit.